# how to set a list of entries text variables to another dynamic list

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there anyway I can plug my list of integers into my list of entry boxes? The list of integers is constantly changing..
This would not be a problem if the list of integers and list of entry boxes had the same number of data points, however I can't determine that initially because I want user input to determine this entry list length in future code. I've tried using Insert to solve this problem, to no avail, given that I couldn't use the index of entry to configure its text option.

```
from tkinter import *
def entry_list_extender():
    entrylist.extend(number)
gx=10
number=0

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()

entry=[]
entrylist=[1,2,3,4]
var = []

entrybox=Entry(frame,bg='blue',textvariable=number)
entrybox.pack()
button=Button(frame,bg='red',command=entry_list_extender)
button.pack()

for i in range(gx):

    entry.append(Entry(frame, textvariable=entrylist[i]))
    entry[-1].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

A solution or path I could take to get the results I want would be appreciated.
Edit: my original question was quite ambiguous. This should make it more clear

Comment: The error I get does not like the list being changing
   entry.append(Entry(frame,textvariable=entrylist[i]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I understand the issue. I would like it to continue with the text variable = the nonexistent variable for the entry boxes it does create

Comment: The way you are trying to extend your `entrylist` will not work here as `for` loop is accessed first and is getting an index error due to the value of `gx` being larger than range(4)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I am going to have to make an assumption here to make this work.

I am assuming that `gx` is the user defined variable you want to use down the road.

If that is the case then you need to change you your code a bit to re-create the entry fields when you press the button and also use the value of `gx` to decide on how many entry fields you should use.

Let me know if this is closer to what you are trying to do as it is still not very clear what your goal is.

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

gx=10
number=0

entry=[]
entrylist=[1, 2, 3, 4]
var = []

def entry_list_extender():
    global frame, entrylist, entry
    entry = []
    entrylist = []
    for i in range(gx):
        entrylist.append(i)
    frame.destroy()
    create_entry_fields()

entrybox=Entry(root, bg='blue', textvariable = number)
entrybox.pack()
button=Button(root, bg='red', command = entry_list_extender)
button.pack()

def create_entry_fields():
    global frame, entrylist, entry
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    print (len(entrylist))
    for i in range(len(entrylist)):
        entry.append(Entry(frame, textvariable = i))
        entry[-1].pack()

create_entry_fields()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My goal is to insert different numbers into each individual entry boxes via button.

Comment: Do you want to insert the same vale to all buttons at the same time or different valuse?

Comment: @KyleEldridge: I have updated my answer however I still am not 100% sure what the end goal is. Your question is still not clear on the intent.

Comment: The end goal is to have a dynamic or changing array. The array is for the purpose "for example" of displaying day to day sales.  This array allows the user to update/change information within the array; by extending the number of data-points/days, editing existing entries/sales, or  importing a list of data from a previous year. To be seperated and displayed for the user to manipulate.                                                                             The entry box and button that do not belong to the array served the purpose of being the delivery that added to the dynamic array.